# django-cms admin very slow on localhost

Tags: django, macos, django-cms

django-cms (v 3.3) has a ~5sec delay on my local machine (OS X 10.11.6) when the admin bar is loaded. The delay does not occur when I'm not logged in to the admin. It seems like the following request is blocking the page:

"GET /en/admin/cms/page/resolve/?model=cms.page&pk=5 HTTP/1.1" 200 4

I tried some solutions to other related problems here like using 127.0.0.1:8000 instead of localhost:8000 and turning off permissions but nothing helps. I also tried to use a sqlite database instead of MySQL and different browsers, but same problem..

Maybe there is a problem with a package? Here is my requirements list:

- Django==1.9.7
- mysqlclient==1.3.7
- django-cms<3.4
- django-treebeard>=4.0
- github.com/divio/djangocms-column/archive/master.zip?1471186721.850163
- github.com/divio/djangocms-googlemap/archive/master.zip?1471186721.850163
- github.com/divio/djangocms-inherit/archive/master.zip?1471186721.850163
- github.com/divio/djangocms-link/archive/master.zip?1471186721.850163
- github.com/divio/djangocms-style/archive/master.zip?1471186721.850163
- easy_thumbnails
- django-filer>=1.2
- cmsplugin-filer>=1.1
- djangocms-admin-style>=1.1.1
- djangocms-text-ckeditor>=3.0
- pytz
- django-reversion==1.10.0
- django-mptt<0.9
- django-classy-tags>=0.7.2
- html5lib>=0.90,!=0.9999,!=0.99999,<0.99999999
- Pillow==3.3.0
- django-sekizai>=0.9.0
- six
- django-settings-export==1.1.0

Does someone experience similar problems with django-cms?

Comment: Hello, can you provide a screen cast that shows the operation being done? as well as the chrome developer tools network tab?

Comment: Sure, here is the screencast with networking tab and console: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=S0GelGu40XU seems like the problem originates from toolbar.min.js.

Comment: Thanks. I recognize the issue. Can you do a pip show django-cms? Would like to confirm the django-cms version installed.

Comment: Sure, here it is - Name: django-cms Version: 3.3.2
Requires: djangocms-admin-style, django-treebeard, Django, django-sekizai, django-formtools, django-classy-tags

Comment: Btw, I uploaded it by now to a digital ocean server, it runs in a docker container and behind nginx and gunicorn, same problem, a little quicker, but you can recognize the delay.

Comment: @toni8xx We've tracked this behavior to an old JS bug. This was fixed on djangoCMS 3.4 which is currently out on rc1. Would you mind upgrading (http://docs.django-cms.org/en/latest/upgrade/3.4.html) to this version? Should be fairly simple :)